# nl2br for paragraphs

Tags: php, paragraph

```
$variable = 'Afrikaans 
Shqip - Albanian  
Euskara - Basque';
```

**How do I convert each new line to paragraph?**

`$variable` should become:

```
<p>Afrikaans</p>
<p>Shqip - Albanian</p>
<p>Euskara - Basque</p>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
$variable = str_replace("\n", "</p>\n<p>", '<p>'.$variable.'</p>');
```

Comment: +1 for keeping line breaks. It's hard as hell to read HTML source without it

Answer (score 4):

The following should do the trick :

```
$variable = '<p>' . str_replace("\n", "</p><p>", $variable) . '</p>';
```

Answer (score 2):

Be careful, with the other proposals, some line breaks are not catch.
This function works on Windows, Linux or MacOS :

```
function nl2p($txt){
    return str_replace(["\r\n", "\n\r", "\n", "\r"], '</p><p>', '<p>' . $txt . '</p>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = explode("\n", $variable);
$newVariable = '<p>'.implode('</p><p>', $array).'</p>'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$variable = 'Afrikaans  
Shqip - Albanian   
Euskara - Basque'; 
$prep0 = str_replace(array("\r\n" , "\n\r") , "\n" , $variable);
$prep1 = str_replace("\r" , "\n" , $prep0);
$prep2 = preg_replace(array('/\n\s+/' , '/\s+\n/') , "\n" , trim($prep1));
$result = '<p>'.str_replace("\n", "</p>\n<p>", $prep2).'</p>'; 
echo $result;
/*
<p>Afrikaans</p>
<p>Shqip - Albanian</p>
<p>Euskara - Basque</p>
*/
?>
```

Explanation:

$prep0 and $prep1: Make sure each line ends with \n.

$prep2: Remove redundant whitespace. Keep linebreaks.

$result: Add p tags.

If you don't include $prep0, $prep1 and $prep2, $result will look like this:

```
<p>Afrikaans  
</p>
<p>Shqip - Albanian   
</p>
<p>Euskara - Basque</p>
```

Not very nice, I think.

Also, don't use preg_replace unless you have to. In most cases, str_replace is faster (at least according to my experience). See the comments below for more information.

Comment: No, I don't agree. isn't it a bit complicated for such a trifle task? and did you **really** experienced any difference between preg_replace and str_replace. I can't believe that.

Comment: Isn't it a bit complicated for such a trifle task? you ask. Well, that depends on whether you care about how your code is formatted or not. If you don't care and think it's ok that your code looks like in the grey box right above, don't use $prep0, $prep1 and $prep2. If you do care, like I do, and want well formatted code, use $prep0, $prep1 and $prep2.

Comment: I believe in optimizing code whenever it's possible. As long as your scripts are relatively small or doesn't handle very big strings or arrays, you won't notice a difference between optimized code and not optimized code. However, if your scripts later become bigger or have to handle bigger strings or arrays you will notice a difference.

Comment: Also, on php.net, the official PHP site, it says on the page http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php: "If you don't need fancy replacing rules (like regular expressions), you should always use this function [str_replace] instead of ereg_replace() or preg_replace()."

Comment: In other words, one str_replace is most likely faster than one preg_replace doing the same thing, while one preg_replace most likely is faster than several str_replace doing the same thing.

Comment: I you still don't believe me, go to some or all of these pages: http://www.php-scripts.com/php_diary/011303.php3 --- 
http://www.simplemachines.org/community/index.php?topic=175031.0 --- http://ilia.ws/files/zend_performance.pdf --- 
http://blogs.digitss.com/php/php-performance-improvement-tips/ --- http://www.hm2k.com/posts/50-php-optimisation-tips-revisited --- 
Or do your own google search for "benchmark str_replace preg_replace" or something like that.

Comment: I have merely asked you if you ever experienced such a difference of your own. In real life, not lame tests. I assume - no.

Comment: As a matter of fact, yes. Among others, I've written scripts to count large number of words (several millions). Using str_replace instead of preg_replace have sometimes made these scripts several seconds faster. At least as I write code. I'm no PHP expert, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$variable = 'Afrikaans
Shqip - Albanian  
Euskara - Basque';

$result = preg_replace("/\r\n/", "<p>$1</p>", $variable);
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old thread, but I want to highlight, that suggested solutions can have some issues in HTML world:

1. They do not check whether there is already a `p` tag around respective paragraph. This can result in extra paragraphs. At least some browsers will then show this as extra paragraphs, meaning `<p>line1<p>line2</p>line3</p>` will result in 3 paragraphs, which may not be the intention.
2. In fact, there is a bunch of tags, that are not expected inside of `p`, as per the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#phrasing-content) of `phrasing content`. Or rather there is a limited set of tags, tha can be.
3. They will change new lines inside tags, where you want to preserve new lines as is. `pre` and `textarea` are the ones, where you could generally want that. `code`, `samp`, `kbd` and `var` are an example of other common values, but technically it can be any tag with `white-space` CSS property set to either `pre`, `pre-wrap`, `pre-line` or `break-spaces`.
4. They usually only check for `\r\n` or just `\r` or `\n`, while there are actually more symbols, that would mean new line, and they also have respective HTML entities, which can easily occur in HTML string.

To "combat" these flaws, at least, to an extent, I've just released a [nl2tag](https://github.com/Simbiat/nl2tag) library, which can also "convert" new lines to `<li>` items and has an "improved" `nl2br` logic (mostly for the sake of whitespace retention).
It's far from perfect (check the readme for limitations), but should cover you in case of relatively simple HTML string.